# Android:After Download file from Server ,how to Encrypt the file before save into SDCARD?

Tags: android

I successfully download and save the file from server to my SDCARD, but i need to **Encrypt** the file before save into the **SDCARD**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `CipherOutputStream` or `CipherInputStream` with a Cipher and your FileOutputStream / FileInputStream. I would suggest something like `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");` to the constructor call. If you want to use a password, please make sure you do use a good key derivation mechanism (look up password based encryption). For multiple files, use an NONCE for the IV (see wikipedia).

Always specify the character encoding when encoding/decoding strings, or you'll be in trouble when the platform encoding differs from the previous one. In other words, don't use `String.getBytes()` but use `String.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))`.

To make it more secure, please add a secure checksum (MAC or HMAC) and don't forget to add the NONCE at the start of the calculation.

Comment: This is my code here i used CipherOutputStream but the file is not encrypt while write into SDCARD                             InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
             File mediaDir = new File("/sdcard/download/media");
             if (!mediaDir.exists()){
                 mediaDir.mkdir();
             }  File resolveMeSDCard = new File("/sdcard/download/media/downloadedfile.jpg");
             resolveMeSDCard.createNewFile();
             OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(resolveMeSDCard);